# is it possible to addEventListener to a table to check for new info in that table?

Tags: javascript, userscripts

i have this greasemonkey/user.js script written for some website. that website has a table which outputs info every now and then; it does so by adding a new tablerow  with the info.

at the moment i just check in a timed loop if there is something new in there. But can i do this different? could i add a listener that will fire whenever a new table row with info appears? if so how?

EDIT: the table i wanna check on consists of only table rows. each time new info is presented a new row is added with some text inside it. the table seems to have a maximum length. so if it's a full table the oldest tr is removed. Think of it as a chatbox, it's quite similar.

my current timed loop checks for untagged table rows in that table, gets the info out of them and tags them. so it checks only untagged ones.

and example of one of those tablerows:

> ```
> <tr class="tagged">
>   <td align="left" style="vertical-align: top;">
>     <div class="someClass" style="width: 100%;">
>       some info i'm interested in
>     </div>
>   </td>
> </tr>
> ```

Comment: edited question. hope it's more clear.

Answer (score 2):

There is [Mutation Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-mutationevents), maybe you can use [DOMNodeInserted](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMNodeInserted) event as there's new rows inserted.

Comment: could you maybe give an example of how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

@wong2 Good call. This works for me (outside of a userscript) in IE9, FF4, Chrome 6:

```
myTable = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];

if (document.implementation.hasFeature('MutationEvents','2.0')
    || window.MutationEvent) {

    myTable.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
        console.log('data added');
    }, false);
}
```

Comment: You don't need the attachEvent branch because all browsers which support DOMNodeInserted also support addEventListener.

Comment: i got this Error: myTable.attachEvent is not a function
in FF4.